# How to trap 403 errors in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a TRY / Catch in my C# code and I want to trap a 403 error so that I can send the user to a registration page.

Is there a property in EXCEPTION for status code (403) or do I have to parse the message ({"The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'."}) ?

I have the following

try

access web service

catch (Exception err)

So I want to be able to find the 403 code in Exception, or should I be using something other than Exception here ?

Answer (score 4):

If it is HttpException, you could use [HttpException.GetHttpCode Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception.gethttpcode.aspx)

Comment: Damn, beat me to it. This is indeed the best way I believe.

Comment: Exception is the parent, base class of all exceptions in .net. It should not and does not contain properties specific to HttpException, as status code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use custom error pages to redirect the use to the login page, in case of a 403 error code. Or try to catch application errors in the `Global.asax`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that this is in an Excel spread sheet using VSTO.